# Spring MVC @SessionAttributes

Tags: java, spring-mvc

here's my code for the controller:
I have put my  object in  a map in the "doLogin" method below and I am trying to access it in my "logout" function but I am getting null value when I am trying to fetch value of my session attribute using "map.get(key)"

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes(value={"session1"})
public class CredentialsController {

    @Autowired
     private Authentication authenticationDao;

    @Autowired
     private User userDao;

    @RequestMapping(value="/start",method=RequestMethod.GET)   //Default Method
    public  String  doStart(@ModelAttribute CredentialsBean credentialsBean)  
    {
        return "login";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/login",method=RequestMethod.GET)   //Default Method
    public  String  doLogin(@ModelAttribute CredentialsBean credentialsBean,Map<String,Object> map)
    {   
        String result="";
        if(credentialsBean!=null){
            if(authenticationDao.authenticate(credentialsBean)){
                String userType=authenticationDao.authorize(credentialsBean.getUserID());
                if(userType.equalsIgnoreCase("A")){

                    CredentialsBean cBean= authenticationDao.changeLoginStatus(credentialsBean, 1);
                    map.put("session1",cBean);  ----->Here I am putting the object inside a map .
                    result= "admin";
                    //map.put("username",credentialsBean.getProfileBean().getFirstName());
                }
                else{


                    CredentialsBean cBean=authenticationDao.changeLoginStatus(credentialsBean, 1);
                    map.put("session1",cBean.getUserID());
                    //System.out.println(cBean.getUserID());
                    result= "customer";

                    //map.put("username",credentialsBean.getProfileBean().getFirstName());
                }
            }
            else{
                result="ERROR";
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/logout",method=RequestMethod.GET)   //Default Method
    public  String  doLogout(Map<String,Object >  map)
    {
        CredentialsBean credentialsBean=(CredentialsBean)map.get("session1");

        //System.out.println(userID);
        System.out.println(credentialsBean.getUserID());
        if(credentialsBean!=null){
            if(userDao.logout(credentialsBean.getUserID())){
                return "logout";
            }
            else{
                return "error1";
            }

        }
        else{
            return "error";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your map in login method isn't saved in a session. You should include `HttpSession` in your method and save your map there. Then retrieve it from session in logout and get your values. Also I suggest you to take a look at Spring Security module.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the way I would do it:
in your `doLogin` method you should add `HttpSession session`:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/login",method=RequestMethod.GET)   //Default Method
public  String  doLogin(@ModelAttribute CredentialsBean credentialsBean, HttpSession session)
{   
    String result="";
    if(credentialsBean!=null){
        if(authenticationDao.authenticate(credentialsBean)){
            String userType=authenticationDao.authorize(credentialsBean.getUserID());
            if(userType.equalsIgnoreCase("A")){

                CredentialsBean cBean= authenticationDao.changeLoginStatus(credentialsBean, 1);
                // add object to session
                session.setAttribute("session1",cBean);
                result= "admin";
                //map.put("username",credentialsBean.getProfileBean().getFirstName());
            }
            else{
                CredentialsBean cBean=authenticationDao.changeLoginStatus(credentialsBean, 1);
                session.setAttribute("session1",cBean);
                result= "customer";
            }
        }
        else{
            result="ERROR";
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Note, that you should add to session objects of the same type in order to safely retrieve it later (because now you added different objects `cBean` and `cBean.getUserID()` for the same key `session1`)

Then in your logout:

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/logout",method=RequestMethod.GET)   //Default Method
    public  String  doLogout(HttpSession session)
    {
        CredentialsBean credentialsBean=(CredentialsBean)session.getAttribute("session1");
       .....
}
```

But anyway, since you're implementing login\logout here I encourage you to learn more about Spring Security.